# How to change the border object's property such as color in Windows Phone 7, once border object is created

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a grid (table) like structure with rows and columns, and I am assigning the background color for every cell using the `border` object.

How do I change the background color for every cell of the grid?

This is my approach:

- Delete the border object and assign it a new one.
- I have also tried to create a new `Border` object, and add it. But it throws `InvalidOperationException` stating "Element is already the child of another element".

How can I change the background color for a particular table row?

Comment: please, don't add a signature to your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I better understand your question...

The following code will give you the border in Row `r` and Column `c`.

```
var border = myGrid.Children.OfType<Border>().Where(x => Grid.GetRow(x) == r && Grid.GetColumn(x) == c).FirstOrDefault();
border.Background = [...];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My Question is if if i want to select the paricular row and change the color ,how can i achieve,i dont have instance of border Object to change the background,Is there any other get around other than this?

Comment: So you have a Grid, in it you have multiple rows and "in each" row you have a border. You want to get the border in row x and change it's Background?

Comment: Yes,Correct this is what i was asking about

Comment: Cool. Edited the answer to do that.

Comment: Hi,Shahar, i tried using your code.I am getting the error as ; expected,I have attached the screen shot with this [link](https://picasaweb.google.com/117897664740476731180/IssueRelatedAlbun#5792362902472459186)

Comment: HI Shahar,Thanks for inputs ,besides I am getting the new error stating  "'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
".On Typing like myGrid.Children.---->not getting type of.I think it is not there

Comment: You need to make sure you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your CS file.

Comment: thanks for your inputs that you have been providing me for the  problems that i am facing.Thanks a lot